# NLP for multi feature data set using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am just a beginner in this subject, I have tested some NN for image recognition as well as using NLP for sequence classification.

This second topic is interesting for me.
using

```
sentences = [
  'some test sentence',
  'and the second sentence'
]
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100, oov_token='<OOV>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
sentences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences)
```

will result with an array of size `[n,1]` where n is word size in sentence. And assuming I have implemented padding correctly each Training example in set will be size of `[n,1]` where n is the max sentence length.

that prepared training set I can pass into keras `model.fit`

what when I have multiple features in my data set?
let's say I would like to build an event prioritization algorithm and my data structure would look like:

`[event_description, event_category, event_location, label]`

trying to tokenize such array would result in [n,m] matrix where n is maximum word length and m is the feature number

how to prepare such a dataset so a model could be trained on such data?

would this approach be ok:

```
# Going through training set to get all features into specific ararys
for data in dataset:
  training_sentence.append(data['event_description'])
  training_category.append(data['event_category'])
  training_location.append(data['event_location'])
  training_labels.append(data['label'])

# Tokenize each array which contains tokenized value 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentence)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_category)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_location)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentence)
categories = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_category)
locations = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_location)

# Concatenating arrays with features into one
training_example = numpy.concatenate([sequences,categories, locations])

#ommiting model definition, training the model
model.fit(training_example, training_labels, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(testing_padded, testing_labels_final))
```

I haven't been testing it yet. I just want to make sure if I understand everything correctly and if my assumptions are correct.

Is this a correct approach to create NPL using NN?

Answer (score 1):

I know of two common ways to manage multiple input sequences, and your approach lands somewhere between them.

---

One approach is to design a multi-input model with each of your text columns as a different input. They can share the vocabulary and/or embedding layer later, but for now you still need a distinct input sub-model for each of description, category, etc.

Each of these becomes an input to the network, using the `Model(inputs=[...], outputs=rest_of_nn)` syntax. You will need to design `rest_of_nn` so it can take multiple inputs. This can be as simple as your current concatenation, or you could use additional layers to do the synthesis.

It could look something like this:

```py
# Build separate vocabularies. This could be shared.
desc_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
desc_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentence)
desc_vocab_size = len(desc_tokenizer.word_index)

categ_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
categ_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_category)
categ_vocab_size = len(categ_tokenizer.word_index)

# Inputs.
desc = Input(shape=(desc_maxlen,))
categ = Input(shape=(categ_maxlen,))

# Input encodings, opting for different embeddings.
# Descriptions go through an LSTM as a demo of extra processing.
embedded_desc = Embedding(desc_vocab_size, desc_embed_size, input_length=desc_maxlen)(desc)
encoded_desc = LSTM(categ_embed_size, return_sequences=True)(embedded_desc)
encoded_categ = Embedding(categ_vocab_size, categ_embed_size, input_length=categ_maxlen)(categ)

# Rest of the NN, which knows how to put everything together to get an output.
merged = concatenate([encoded_desc, encoded_categ], axis=1)
rest_of_nn = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(merged)
rest_of_nn = Flatten()(rest_of_nn)
rest_of_nn = Dense(output_size, activation='softmax')(rest_of_nn)

# Create the model, assuming some sort of classification problem.
model = Model(inputs=[desc, categ], outputs=rest_of_nn)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=K.categorical_crossentropy)
```

---

The second approach is to concatenate all of your data before encoding it, and then treat everything as a more standard single-sequence problem after that. It is common to use a unique token to separate or define the different fields, similar to `BOS` and `EOS` for the beginning and end of the sequence.

It would look something like this:

```
XXBOS XXDESC This event will be fun. XXCATEG leisure XXLOC Seattle, WA XXEOS
```

You can also do end tags for the fields like `DESCXX`, omit the `BOS` and `EOS` tokens, and generally mix and match however you want. You can even use this to combine some of your input sequences, but then use a multi-input model as above to merge the rest.

---

Speaking of mixing and matching, you also have the option to treat some of your inputs directly as an embedding. Low-cardinality fields like `category` and `location` do not need to be tokenized, and can be embedded directly without any need to split into tokens. That is, they don't need to be a sequence.

If you are looking for a reference, I enjoyed this paper on [Large Scale Product Categorization using Structured and Unstructured Attributes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04254). It tests all or most of the ideas I have just outlined, on real data at scale.